# perfect three part css background

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-color

I would like a fixed contain image in the middle and a green color background on the left of the image if any space free and a blue color background on the right of it.

This is what I got so far (the problem is not with the image, but with two separate backgrounds for the left and right; if I change color green on the left to bmp with the size of 200px(600px) and height 1 and repeat-y this may be seen on the right of the image also or not all space of the left of the image will be covered):
Note that I may solve in 99% cases for this image, but I have different proportion images to work on that ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lab 2</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #546436
      /*#6096ec*/
      url('https://lilaum.com/pic/jaka.jpg' no-repeat fixed center center;
      background-size: contain;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <pre>
    more
    to 
    do

    Please help me, smth like to repeat just to 50% of page should be perfect, thanks, Grega from Slovenia
    </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple backgrounds and a linear gradient

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-image: url('https://lilaum.com/pic/jaka.jpg'), linear-gradient(to right, #546436 50%, #6096ec 50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain, cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of gradient along with background image.

See this working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ged4sj35/

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://lilaum.com/pic/jaka.jpg"), 
  -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, red 50%, blue 50%, blue);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}
```